# Sometimes I have no picture on the screen at boot on my laptop

Tags: boot, opensuse

I never gave much importance because this happened to me too from time to time. What looked like a minor issue, but now I take this phenomenon has become very annoying indeed. I do not know how to begin to debug the problem ... any ideas? May well reach a solution.

### [UPDATE]

Will try to explain my self a little better;
When I turn on the notebook, the load grub ok.

After that, will I notice when I go to see the welcome screen only when if I see for a split of a second *"creating node with uuid"* If you do not see it means that I will see the black screen, but I notice that the disk is still working.

### [DETAILS]

My laptop is a `Acer Aspire 5253-0435` with 3gb of ram.
Video is `AMD Radeon HD 6320`.

```
 # lspci | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Wrestler [Radeon HD 6320]
```

My OS is `Opensuse 12.2` my filesystem is reiserfs.

Comment: No bootsplash? Is that what you mean by no pictures or grub?

Comment: sorry about my english I meant video... after grub it's all over. XD

Comment: Tell us more about your system. Which OS on what hardware? This might be an issue with your video card.

Comment: Are you using the AMD-drivers or the free drivers?

Comment: will add that info. check it out

Comment: Look for your distribution's incantations to boot the machine without boot splash, so you see what is going on. Perhaps in `/var/log/messages` there are some hints (look around the latest lines talking about boot).

Comment: Do you have another machine so you can try to connect to the patient via ssh(1) or check if it is responsive via ping(1)? Or just CapsLock/NumLock LEDs? If it doesn't answer, it might just have shut down due to CPU overheating. Or due to problems with the graphics card (update your installation and try again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking around turn out that my /etc/fstab and turn out that my grub and my fstab uses diferent path to / one by uuid ant the other one by /dev/sda2 ... cahanged all to uuid and start working ok.

that "creating node with uuid" it was wrong when my fstab was whit /dev/sda2..

thanks every one!